# What are deadlifts good for?

Tags: deadlifts, barbell, programming

I’ve been exploring various pre-made all rounder types of workout programs and have often noticed that they exclude deadlifts, even when they are all made up of classic barbell power lifts: bench presses, squats, rows, overhead presses, variations of those, but very often no dead lifts, suggesting to me that deadlifts might be a bit redundant. Would dead lifts be redundant to a program that already included all of those other lifts? If not then what is likely the reason that deadlifts seem to be omitted from so many readymade workout programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak as to why these workout plans omit the deadlifts but I can say they are a very useful movement. Deadlifts focus more on the posterior chain; mainly glutes and hamstrings, but also the lower back and lats. Probably the most important point to consider, do you enjoy deadlifts? Unless you're a pro bodybuilder, don't worry too much about the most *optimal* programming and just do what you enjoy.

So no, deadlifts aren't redundant as they target different parts of the lower body than squats and other legs exercises.